# PCA on Stock Returns

Tags: r, pca

I am working on a homework problem, but I'm still having some issues connecting the text / theory to R. The question at hand is:

[image]

Now, as far as code, goes, I we worked an example in class, which I used to get me to where I needed to be, but I am having some issues understanding how to apply R to these to derive a solution. Right now I am just stuck on part (a), but I do some some questions about the other items as well, but we can start here. As for the code to do the PCA, here is what I have:

```
    # Perform a PCA using the corrlelation matrix
boxplot(stock)

R <- cor(stock)
R
eig <- eigen(R)
eig$vectors # This is "C", the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of R

eig$values
eig$values / sum(eig$values)
cumsum(eig$values / sum(eig$values))

mean(eig$values) #is one since using correlation matrix
plot(eig$values, type = 'b')

pcaOut <- princomp(stock, cor = T)
attributes(pcaOut)
pcaOut$loadings  #compare to eig$vectors
pcaOut$scores
(pcaOut$sdev)^2  #compare to eig$values
eig$values  

# Using the princomp() function
pcaOut <- princomp(stock[,1:5], cor = T)
attributes(pcaOut)
pcaOut$loadings  #compare to eig$vectors
pcaOut$scores
(pcaOut$sdev)^2  #compare to eig$values
eig$values
```

Also, I've uploaded the data file here:

http://thetruthindata.com/stock.dat

From what I can see in the text, for part (a) we just take the variance of the 2nd linear combination, which ends up being a combination of those x values along with variances and covariance of the variables. I'm just trying to connect how to apply that or if I am even on the right track. I would think, in R, there would be an easy way to do this without a ton of coding.

Thanks for any help to nudge me in right direction on part (a), when I get that figured out, I'm sure I'll need some nudging on some of the rest too.

Comment: I figured out part (a) - I believe I just take the (eigenvalue/p)*100, which is 28.104%. I'm basing this off of the text I am using (Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis, Johnson & Wichern 6th Edition, page 453). Have I interpreted this correctly?

Comment: For part (b) I am not able to figure out how these values were derived, they do not match what my output is.... Any ideas?